# override_dh_auto_install doesn't run during debuild

Tags: makefile, debian, package

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Intro?action=show&redirect=IntroDebianPackaging) to create a Debian package.
My makefile is this:

```
prefix = /usr/local
includedir = $(prefix)/include

install:
    cp -r ./Include/* $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)

uninstall:
    rm -rf $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/ftz/Console
```

My `debian/rules` is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_install:
    $(MAKE) DESTDIR=$$(pwd)/debian/libftzconsole prefix=/usr install
```

I'm running `debuild -us -uc` and my build log is this:

```
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package libftzconsole
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 2016.06.03-1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by FaTony <fatony@fatony.net>
 dpkg-source --before-build fTzConsole
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b fTzConsole
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building libftzconsole using existing ./libftzconsole_2016.06.03.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building libftzconsole in libftzconsole_2016.06.03-1.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: building libftzconsole in libftzconsole_2016.06.03-1.dsc
 debian/rules build
dh build
   dh_testdir
   dh_update_autotools_config
   dh_auto_configure
   dh_auto_build
    make -j1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/fatony/Stuff/C++/fTzConsole'
cp -r -i ./Include/* /usr/local/include
cp: './Include/ftz/Console' and '/usr/local/include/ftz/Console' are the same file
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fatony/Stuff/C++/fTzConsole'
dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
debian/rules:4: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

It looks like `override_dh_auto_install` doesn't run and it tries to install the package directly to my system. The cp error is because I've symlinked the directory.

I'm not sure how to fix it. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so `debuild` calls `dh build` which calls `dh_auto_build` which calls `make -j1` which selects the 1st goal which is `install`.

When I've added

```
all:
```

before `install` to makefile, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and simply removed that `override` part. It worked.